# Create new join table row without overwriting existing rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add users through a frontend button to an organization. Their relationship is defined as:

#### Organization model

`has_many :users, through: :organization_user_assignments`

#### User model

`has_many :organizations, through: :organization_user_assignments`

#### Front end form

To add users I currently have a drop down menu to select a user:

```
<%= form_for @organization, url: organization_path(@organization), html: { method: :put } do |f| %>

  <%= f.select :user_ids, User.order('first_name ASC').map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, 
  { selected: params[:organization_user_id] || @organization.user_ids, include_blank: '-Users-' },
  'aria-describedby': 'requested_org_hint', 'data-org-toggle': 'org-toggle' %>

  <%= f.submit "Add User" %>
<% end %>
```

It will add the selected user but remove any existing users already in the organization.

I understand that the `put` action is using the Organization Controllers to update the whole organization (as seen below)

```
    def update
      @organization = Organization.find params[:id]

      if @organization.update organization_params
        flash[:notice] = 'Organization updated.'
        redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Organization could not be updated."
        render :edit
      end
    end
```

How do I specify that I only want to add a new user to existing users in the organization?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms)? Does your `Organization` model have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`? I would think your form would show a list of existing users for the organization, using `fields_for` and then you'd be updating that particular list via the view and controller.

Comment: I can add the users individually by assigning them an organization one at a time on their edit pages. The current form above was what I adapted from that user form.

Comment: The basic issue in your current form is that it is strictly being treated as an update to the organization, not to the users. That makes since since your view is implementing as a simple organization edit form. Having the `form_for` on the organization makes sense, but you probably want a `fields_for` to cover the users. That should get you a params set that is for the association. You'd want, on your organization edit form, to show the list of current users (or possibly with a "dialog") and let the app user edit the list of users particular to that organization.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, and I am trying to get the app user to edit the list of users particular to that organization, I'm just stuck